# Unstick a reboot when PsKill doesn't work

Tags: windows, rdp

I tried to remote into a server today and got stuck during login. So I tried to reboot with:

```
shutdown -r -m \\computername -t 10 -f
```

And nothing seemed to happen. So I tried it again and got:

```
computername: A system showdown is in progress.(1115)
```

So googling around for ways to unstick it, I came across [this](http://www.ryansteele.ca/2011/01/21/unstick-a-remote-reboot/) which suggested using PSKill. So I downloaded [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) and tried:

```
PsKill \\computername winlogon
```

But now that just sticks at:

```
Starting PsKill service on computername...
```

Now what? Any suggestions from here?

Answer (score 0):

What state is the machine currently at physically? Can you view the display?
If it has already stopped the user profile service and logged the account off you either need to wait or force the machine to power off. If it has not you can issue a `shutdown -a` this will abort the shutdown and you can try again, before doing this check the eventlogs for any possible cause of the delay, as a note set the `-t` option to `0` unless you want to wait 10 seconds for the shutdown to happen of course.

Comment: Note that the 'shutdown' command asks the server to shutdown processes, etc. gracefully for the shutdown. PsKill does that, kills them off, if you can get access to the machine locally to run this you can kill the stuck process off.

Comment: I tried `-a`, but that didn't work. But hang on, now it seems to be responding again. I think it finally sorted out whatever was hanging it up.

Comment: Patience is a virtue :-D

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to simply wait 2+ hours for system updates to complete.

I just encountered a similar situation and it turned out to be due to just standing up a new server that had a million patches to download and install.

Initial reboot was requested via start menu->restart and it logged me out but then I was unable to log back in. No error messages from RDP but it would just close the session even when I tried the `mstsc /console` trick.

I was able to pskill winlogon but it still wouldn't reboot.

None of the `shutdown -r -f` or `shutdown -a` commands would do anything except tell me a shutdown was already in progress.

Then I found the real cause by issuing a VERBOSE tasklist command `tasklist /S RemotePcName /V` and noticing that **TiWorker.exe** task was rapidly accumulating total CPU time. This is the TrustedInstaller worker process which indicated that there was some kind of patching going on. TiWorker would count up for a while, then complete whatever it was installing and move on to the next TiWorker process counting up from 00:00 CPU time again.

If I didn't see actual activity on **TiWorker.exe** I would've assumed the system was just in a completely broken state and I would have needed to find a VM cluster administrator to force a reboot, which would have probably interrupted some patch installers that could lead to issues down the road.